# Database relations between each other (users and groups)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling

Im doing a project for tutorships in a school, while making the database im having trouble desinging the best way of getting a relation between groups, users, and the tutor of the group in the database.

I have students, teachers, tutors, save in my "users" table 
One group has many students, but only a tutor.

The way i think of doing it is adding a foreign key in my users table, so my users that are students, belongs to a group and each "group" has a tutor, so i need to add a foreign key to "users in the "groups" table, but im not sure if this is the best approach.

So im asking for some suggestions, thx for reading

Comment: If you will be showing actual `CREATE TABLE` statements for "many-to-many" tables, please follow the tips I provide [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Adding TutorID in the GroupTable is okay.

Create a table 'GroupTable' with columns 'GroupID'(PrimaryKey),'GroupName','TutorID'(ForeignKey with Users table).

Create a table 'StudentGroupMapping' with columns 'StudentID'(Foreignkey with Users),'GroupID'(ForeignKey with GroupTable). Primary key of this table can be composite primarykey of (StudentID, GroupID). With this, we can make a Student belong to multiple groups.

The integrity we need to take care is that a User marked as Tutor doesn't come into Student.

Answer (score 0):

So, in total, you should have the following three tables. The third table would play the role of bridge table.

- Users
- Groups
- GroupUserRelation

Users:

- user_id (PK)
- username
- role (i.e. student, teacher, tutor)

Groups:

- group_id (PK)
- user_id (FK) (i.e. tutor_id)
- group_name
- group_timings

GroupUserRelation:

- group_id (FK)
- user_id (FK) (i.e. student_id)

The group_id and user_id would combine to be a composite key.

This way you could define a many-to-many relation between students and tutor if needed in the future. For example, a tutor can teach many groups and one student can enroll in many groups as well.